# How to set opacity on UICollectionView background without affect opacity of UICollectionViewCell?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have set the color of a `UICollectionView` with an `image` pattern like so:

```
self.collectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:image];
```

I would like to set the alpha of the `collectionView` without affecting the alpha of the `UICollectionViewCell`. Is there a way to do this? Setting the alpha of `collectionView` also affects the `UICollectionViewCell`, so I already tried that. What else should I try/what else will actually work?

Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `-colorWithAlphaComponent:` method of `UIColor`:

```
[self.collectionView setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor redColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5]];
```

This will result in *only* the background having a non-1 alpha value.

Answer (score 3):

If you only want to change the opacity without changing the color or need to keep track of the color itself, you can use:

```
self.collectionView.backgroundColor = [self.collectionView.backgroundColor colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5f];
```

There are two possible "backgrounds" on `UICollectionView` that you may want to change the opacity of. The `backgroundColor` property is the simplest, but only changes the full color background. There's also the `backgroundView` which can have subviews which will not change opacity if you just change the background color opacity. You can change the opacity of the `backgroundView` with:

```
self.collectionView.backgroundView.alpha = 0.5f;
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4 Solution:

```
self.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
```